# Jquery plugin to display events on a timeline

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a Jquery plugin (or AngularJS plugin, Bootstrap whatever...) to display events on some kind of Timeline (I already had a look on TimelineJS) with a constant focus on current time (like a monitor of upcoming and past events).

The idea is to have a look on the upcoming events with a regular refresh, with the next event becoming closer and closer...

I hope somebody will understand what I mean (sorry if the explaination are too bad :D  ) and help me !

Comment: In fact, the best way to solve it would be to use some kind of timeline like this : http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/ and add a way to keep focus on current time.. That is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Why not having a setInterval with some centering method call ? I do use setVisibleChartRangeNow() with this API http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/timeline/doc/

Comment: looks good, thanks a lot, i keep you posted.

Comment: with the API you mentionned, you could go with http://simile-widgets.org/wiki/Timeline_Moving_the_Timeline_via_Javascript

Comment: Indeed, really appreciate your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to  Zzirconium i found the solution !

I used his link : http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/timeline/doc/ and then create with Angular a loop on every 1s to call setVisibleChartRangeNow() as he suggested.

Thanks a lot man !